# Flask-SQLAlchemy whats the difference db.Column vs Column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am making new flask app and noticed even in other projects that `db.Column` and `Column` is used interchangeably. So when do you use one over the other?

```
id = db.Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

vs

```
id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

It appears to be a convenience; there is no difference.

```
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>> db = SQLAlchemy()
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column
>>> db.Column is Column
True
```

In the docstring of the class `SQLAlchemy` you may see [this comment](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/5ac5ab47db1f0acaaf8e9f94258a6d599a04bb38/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L618-L624):

> This class also provides access to all the SQLAlchemy functions and classes from the `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy.orm` modules.

The names are provided by a helper function [`_include_sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/5ac5ab47db1f0acaaf8e9f94258a6d599a04bb38/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L77-L87) that get's [called in `SQLAlchemy`'s initializer](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/5ac5ab47db1f0acaaf8e9f94258a6d599a04bb38/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L680).  A questionable design choice, perhaps, disregarding zen of Python #13 for no reason other than to reduce the number of import statements at the top of the module?